# Xamarin Forms App freezes on Windows (UWP) when using Frame

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms app that has always worked without any problems. Now problems have suddenly occurred on certain hardware when I want to enter data in an entry - the app freezes completely. After a lot of testing, I discovered that this only happens if you want to use an element (like an entry or something similar) within a frame.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Xamarin Forms app (v5).
2. Place the following code in e.g. MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Frame HasShadow="false" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0">
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry Margin="40, 0, 40 ,0 " TextColor="Black"/>
                <Entry Margin="40, 0, 40 ,0 " TextColor="Black"/>
                <Entry Margin="40, 0, 40 ,0 " TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```

3. Start the application
4. Try to click on all entries with the pointer

Platform:
The problem only occurs for me with Windows 10 version 22H2 build 19045.3803. Everything works perfectly on another computer with Windows 11.

Looks to me like I might have to reach out to Microsoft. But the situation is a bit urgent. Does anyone have an idea for a workaround without having to modify the 800 frames in my application?

Comment: I tested on my side and it worked well on windows11. It might be an issue which only occurred on the windows10. It is recommended to report it on the GitHub issue.